# Checking the convergence of $\int _{-1}^{1} \frac{2^{\arcsin x}}{1-x}\, dx$ and an another integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need to check convergence of

- $$\int _{-1}^{1} \frac{2^{\arcsin x}}{1-x}\, dx$$
- $$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\frac{x}{\cos x}\cdot \sin\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)dx$$

**My attempt:**

For the first one, what I did :

$$0\le \frac{2^{\arcsin x}}{1-x}\le \frac{2^2}{\left(1-x\right)^1}$$

so the integral convergences.

Is this correct, and any idea how to check the second one?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: the first integral doesn't converge on the given interval

Comment: The second one does.

Comment: For the first one, you should use $\frac{2^{\arcsin(x)}}{1-x}\geq \frac{2^0}{1-x}=\frac1{1-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet$ For the first one, the inequality you used does not justify the convergence around $x=1^{-}$. However, to study around $1$ you can change to $x=1-h$. Then
$$
\frac{2^{\text{arcsin}\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\underset{h \rightarrow 0}{\sim}\frac{2^{\, \pi/2}}{h}
$$
However $\displaystyle h \mapsto \frac{1}{h}$ diverges around $0$ so as your integral.

$\bullet$ To help you with the second one, you can analyze instead the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin\left(v\right) \text{arctan}\left(v\right)}{\left(1+v^2\right)\cos\left(\text{arctan}\left(v\right)\right)}\text{d}v=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin\left(v\right) \text{arctan}\left(v\right)}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}\text{d}v
$$
The function within the integral is continous in $\left[0,+\infty\right[$ and satisfies
$$
\left|\frac{\sin\left(v\right) \text{arctan}\left(v\right)}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}\right|\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin\left(v\right)}{v}
$$
Then, it is semi-convergent as Dirichlet's integral.

By changing variable $x=\text{arctan}\left(v\right)$, you found it is equal to your second integral.